# Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $W$ an irreducible representation of $H$. Then $gW$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $W_{i}$ be the irreducible representations of $H$. I want to show that for each $g \in G$, $gW_{i}$ is also an irreducible representation. It is easy to show that $gW_{i}$ is $H-$stable and thus a representation of $H$;

$$hgW_{i}=g(g^{-1}hg)W_{i}=gW_{i}$$

It is also easy to see that $W_{i}$ and $gW_{i}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces and so in particular have the same dimension.

I feel like it show be easy to see that $gW_{i}$ is also irreducible, but I just can't seem to get my head around it. A little hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try by contrapositive. Show that if $gW_i$ has a proper subrepresentation, then so must $W_i = g^{-1}(gW_i)$.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great idea!